# Why would TLS version in one config cause another to break?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4, proxy, 502

I have an Apache proxy that has several VHosts. Some of these are legacy configs that were before my time. Long story short, I removed some .crt files on the server that had expired, and forgot to remove the associated `/etc/apache2/ssl/*.conf` files, so when Apache would try to rotate its logs, it would fail.

After repairing that mess, I began receiving `502 Proxy Error` when navigating to **only one** of the `VHosts`. All the others worked.

This is what was causing everything to break. In one of the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf` files, there was this line:

```
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
#SSLProxyProtocol +TLSv1 <---- THIS BROKE IT
```

All the other `VHosts` are using `TLSv1.2`. My question is, why would this make only ONE `VHost` break and not all of them, especially when it wasn't even the config that had the old `TLS` in the file?

**Update** I set Apache's log level to `debug`, and it shows the error, but doesn't tell me which config file was the culprit. Luckily, I know which one:

```
[Mon Aug 30 08:26:35.098657 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 10843] SSL Library Error: error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version (SSL alert number 70)
[Mon Aug 30 08:26:35.098679 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 10843] [remote 192.168.66.120:8004] AH01998: Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server www.example.com:443)
[Mon Aug 30 08:26:35.098715 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 10843] [remote 192.168.66.120:8004] AH01997: SSL handshake failed: sending 502
```